# Increasing Glimpse History tab limit

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

The documentation [says](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/wiki/History-Tab):

> What happens when the maximum number of stored requests is reached (by
>   default 25)?
>
> Internally we store the requests in a FIFO Queue. This means that when
>   the maximum number spaces in the queue are filled, we take the first
>   one that was entered and remove it from the queue, thus making room
>   for the new request.

How to increase this limit of 25? I want to use Glimpse to gather data and then dig it to diagnose after 30 users in 30 minutes session so there will be a lot more requests than 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a boneheaded mistake, by me, the number of requests that Glimpse stores, which is supposed to be configurable, isn't.

The offending line can be seen in our implementation of [`ApplicationPersistanceStore`](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Framework/ApplicationPersistenceStore.cs#L19).

Your best bet to get this running quickly is to build Glimpse yourself (very easy to do) and change `BufferSize` to whatever you see fit.

Alternately, you could implement your own `IPersistanceStore` and have it do whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can now add `requestBufferSize` to glimpse runtime policy to change it

```
   <glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd" requestBufferSize="100">
      <!-- Additional Glimpse configuration nodes -->
   </glimpse>
```

But you have to build your own Glimpse from sources for that to work